# Is it possible to have a Data validation with a Custom formula WITH a dropdown list?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a Data validation of *Custom formula* on a cell, B8, that looks a little like this:

```
=or(and(B7="Yes",isblank(B8)),and(B7="No",B8>=75,B8<=100))`
```

I'd like to turn the latter validation of `B8>=75,B8<=100` into a drop-down selection with the numbers 75-100—is that possible? I only know you can with the *List of items* option.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using *List from a range* criterion.

On another sheet, say Sheet2, enter conditional formulas that will be either blank or a number, based on B7 cell. Like this, entered in cells A1:A26 of Sheet2:

```
=if(Sheet1!$B$7="Yes",,row()-row(A$1)+75)
```

This will be either blank or the numbers 75..100.

In B8 of Sheet1, use data validation "List from a range": Sheet2!A1:A26 . This will give you in-cell dropdown, which will be either empty or contain numbers 75..100, depending on what's in B7 of Sheet1.